# Drupal Flexslider conflict

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, drupal-7, flexslider

I've got a site that i'm having trouble using Flexslider on. I think i've done my due diligence searching for issues like it on forums and the project page, and didn't want to post an issue because i think it's site specific. I did the same install on another site of mine and it worked fine.

My site is here, and there are a few flexslider slideshows, but here's one of them:
http://www.thefernandez.com/new-al/portfolio/retail/caronel-watch-center

Can you see any reason why the nav buttons and pager don't show up on this site? It’s just the text below (prev and next) that appears on hover.

I only want the default basic slider to work - with the nav buttons on hover and pager on the bottom of the image.

thank you and I would really appreciate your help. I feel like someone with more programming skills might be able to see the problem.

Comment: You have a JS error in your Drupal: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null ". Maybe this is the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The markup is all there for pagination and the arrows. They're just missing some styles or settings.

1. In `flexslider.css` you have `.flex-control-nav` set to `display: none;` If you remove that style the pagination dots will appear.
2. The "Previous" and "Next" buttons are the default arrows, but they're missing their styling. In the same `flexslider.css` file, the section that styles the control nav is commented out. See lines 61 - 72 after the `/* Control Nav */` line. If you uncomment them the arrows appear overlaying the slider on hover, though they need some more styling help.
3. You do get a javascript error on that page from `twitterFetcher.js`. It doesn't seem to be breaking anything, but fixing it might solve your problem.

I've used flexslider, but not the drupal module for it, I'd suggest reading the flexslider API and any documentation in the module. You may need to select a slider theme, use a different wrapping class, or pass in some custom options to get the navigation you want.

Flexslider: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: you are awesome! thank you so much for your help. i'm a css newbie, but i couldn't figure out how to fix that at all. you definitely pointed me in the right direction.